# Retrieving and displaying JSON data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to retrieve and display information about current weather from a JSON object using javascript and a URL request:

```
http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=de39ga&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=ec9c2dc5ba201904120805'
```

the data from the URL looks like this:

```
   {
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [
            {
                "cloudcover": "75",
                "humidity": "88",
                "observation_time": "03:30 PM",
                "precipMM": "2.7",
                "pressure": "1008",
                "temp_C": "12",
                "temp_F": "54",
                "visibility": "8",
                "weatherCode": "302",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Moderate rain"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0018_cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SE",
                "winddirDegree": "140",
                "windspeedKmph": "17",
                "windspeedMiles": "11"
            }
        ],
        "request": [
            {
                "query": "DE3",
                "type": "Postcode"
            }
        ],
        "weather": [
            {
                "date": "2012-05-09",
                "precipMM": "11.8",
                "tempMaxC": "13",
                "tempMaxF": "56",
                "tempMinC": "12",
                "tempMinF": "53",
                "weatherCode": "266",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Light drizzle"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SE",
                "winddirDegree": "141",
                "winddirection": "SE",
                "windspeedKmph": "12",
                "windspeedMiles": "7"
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-05-10",
                "precipMM": "11.1",
                "tempMaxC": "18",
                "tempMaxF": "64",
                "tempMinC": "6",
                "tempMinF": "43",
                "weatherCode": "353",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Light rain shower"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SSW",
                "winddirDegree": "209",
                "winddirection": "SSW",
                "windspeedKmph": "30",
                "windspeedMiles": "19"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of scripts to try and get the data and take bits out to display in a div. The first one looks like this:

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=de39ga&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=ec9c2dc5ba201904120805"
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function() {
            alert("HELLO");
            alert("Current Cloud Cover = " + this.data.current_condition.cloudcover);
            alert("Current Humidity = " + this.data.current_condition.humidity);
        });
    }
});
```

the second one looks like this:

```
var postcode = document.getElementById("address").value;

function getWeather(userName, count) {

   $.getJSON(
     'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q' + postcode + '&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=ec9c2dc5ba201904120805', 
     {}, 
     showWeather,
    //'jsonp'
  );
```

}

```
function showWeather(day) {

    var str = '<ul>';
    str += '<h2>Tweets from ' + postcode + '</h2>';
    var i = 0;
    $.each(day, function(index, value) {
        if (i == count) return;
        var dt = new Date(value.date);
        str += '<p>';
        str += value.temp_C; //gets "text" from JSON
        str += '</p>';
        str += '';
        str += '';
        i++;
    });
}
```

I want to get the weather information from the JSON URL and display some of the information in a div, can anybody explain how to do this is these two scripts dont work.

Comment: Can you post the error message, if there is one?  (The easiest way to see the error is to use Google Chrome, right click the page, select "Inspect Element", and then click on the "Console" tab to bring up a JavaScript console.)  I suspect you're getting a cross-site scripting error because you're trying to download data from a different domain.  I think you'll need to do some server-side work to get this to work.

Comment: Thansk for the reply, however nothing displays in my console window.

Comment: Does the `alert("Hello")` get produced in your first attempt?

Comment: Your `showWeather()` function never actually returns or echos any code - perhaps (in the second example, using getJSON), the code works fine but you are never doing anything with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=de39ga&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=ec9c2dc5ba201904120805",
    dataType: 'jsonp',  // You  need to use 'jsonp' here because it is cross domain request 
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            alert(value.current_condition[0].cloudcover);
            alert(value.current_condition[0].humidity);
            alert(value.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value);
            alert(value.request[0].query);
            alert(value.request[0].query);
            $.each(value.weather, function(i, val) {
                alert(val.precipMM);
                alert(val.weatherDesc[0].value);
            })
        });
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/26/)**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems... the following should work (modification of the first block of code).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=de39ga&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=ec9c2dc5ba201904120805&callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        jQuery.each(data, function(){
            alert(JSON.stringify(this));
            alert("Current Cloud Cover = " + this.current_condition[0].cloudcover);
            alert("Current Humidity = " + this.current_condition[0].humidity);
        });
    }
});
```

To recap:

1. You need to use **JsonP** to circumvent cross-site-scripting restrictions (do that by adding "&callback=?" to the AJAX URL.
2. The root of the JSON response is **data**, so you need to write data.data.
3. The **current_condition** property is an array-- have to add an indexer (ie, [0]) to access it.

Comment: In the alerts, why are you using `data.data` and not `this.data` ? there is a loop going on that uses `jQuery.each(data, function(){...});` - also, current_condition  is an array, but it there is no array of `current_condition` objects, so shouldnt it be `this.data.current_condition` and `this.data.request`, etc..

Comment: @Dutchie432 good question.  The answer involves caffeine and the absence thereof.  Corrected.